# I want to compress a byte[] and return a byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, compression

I want to write a method in C# that takes a byte[] and compress it to another byte[], but all I can find is libraries that compress from a directory to another directory (the [ZipFile library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280.aspx)).

Is it possible to do using only the .NET platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to do using only the .NET platform?

Sure - that's exactly what the [`System.IO.Compression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z72378a.aspx) namespace is for. For example, you could use the [`GZipStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) class. Use a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) to receive the compressed data, and then you can call [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) afterwards.

Sample code (untested):

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    using (var output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var compression = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            compression.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        return output.ToArray();
    }
}

public static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    using (var output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var compression = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            compression.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        return output.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You could also use `DeflateStream` as an alternative compression form.